# Trigger in oracle. Update field when insert or update another field

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need To update the field `DATAMARKER`"of my table `LOG_ALARMA` when I have one `INSTER` or `UPDATE` of "`CONTADOR`".

i have this, but return muting error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER2 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CONTADOR ON LOG_ALARMA
for each row
BEGIN
  UPDATE LOG_ALARMA a 
  SET a.DATAMARKER=(SYSDATE);
END;
```

I look another examples and they work but i can't execute this correctly.

IF i comment the line for each row in my trigger body then it is working fine but it `UPDATES` all the rows in my table.

Comment: if the trigger reads a table, it can not change the table that it read from. That's why you got Mutating error.

Comment: I think you trying to log when the record was updated. For this why don't you create a history table and log the changes with the help of trigger.

Comment: Use `:new.datamarker := sysdate`; in a **BEFORE** trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You do not issue an update SQL statement, because that would again cause the trigger to fire.

Instead, you just set the value :new.DATAMARKER to sysdate, using PL/SQL not SQL.

Make it a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE also.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Mutating
(
  ID1    NUMBER,
  DATE1  DATE
)
```

data present in a table is

```
ID1 DATE1
1   09/01/2015 14:09:14
1   08/31/2015 14:09:21
2   08/30/2015 14:09:30
```

Now i want to update the date1 if any update happens on id1 column in that situation i have used trigger look below.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Mutating_trg
        before INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Mutating
     referencing old as old new as new 
        for  each row 

        begin

            if updating  then
             :new.date1:=sysdate;
            end if;

    end;
```

then i have issued update statement

```
    update set Mutating id1=6 where trunc(date1)=trunc(sysdate-2)
    1 row updated
```

Now look into results

```
ID1 DATE1
1   09/01/2015 14:09:14
6   09/02/2015 14:09:14
2   08/30/2015 14:09:30
```

You should use before statement.

Comment: You don't need a query to assign sysdate to a variable in PL/SQL.

Comment: I am upvoting your comment, horsey!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i know no need for select statement. so i have updated it thanks.